# For every integer $n$ , find how many elements of order $n$ there are in $S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that $S_5$ has order $5!$, knowing that numebr of elements of order $n$  refers to the number of elements $x$ such that $x^n$ is the identity element, but $x^m$ is not for any $m<n$. However, I don't know where to start to solve the question.

Answer (score 6):

Write an element of $S_5$ in its cycle form. If there are cycles of length $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$, then it is not hard to show that the element has order $\text{lcm}(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$.

The different combinations of cycles which can appear are precisely the partitions of $5$, i.e.
$$
\begin{align*}
1+1+1+1+1\\
2+1+1+1\\
2+2+1\\
3+1+1\\
3+2\\
4+1\\
5
\end{align*}
$$
Elements of the resulting form have orders $1,2,2,3,6,4,5$ (by taking lcms). Do you see how to finish from here?